# Embedded True Streaming in Webpage

Tags: html, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, video-streaming

I am a student doing research under a professor at a University and he has asked me to stream video onto a webpage. All of my attempts up until now are not what he has wanted. I have tried from Ampache (a personal streaming server) and the Video Tag in HTML5. He doesn't want me to use downloading or progressive streaming. He wants me to use true streaming and embed it into a webpage.

Is there a way to do this?

Currently, I am hosting through Amazon Web Services (AWS) with an EC2 Instance running Ubuntu 14.04 and Apache2.

My previous attempt involved using:

```
<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" WIDTH="320"HEIGHT="180"
CODEBASE="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab">
<PARAM name="SRC" VALUE="videofilename.mov">
<PARAM name="AUTOPLAY" VALUE="true">
<PARAM name="CONTROLLER" VALUE="false">
<EMBED SRC="videofilename.mov" WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="180" AUTOPLAY="true" CONTROLLER="false" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/">
</EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```

This method, I believe, uses downloading.

I was looking into creating a .m3u stream. Would that work?

Any way to stream from my Ubuntu server to either an embedded player or Windows Media Player or VLC would even work.

All methods must be free.

Comment: What is "true streaming?" How "true" does it have to be?  The assignment seems vague.

Comment: The project so far has been very vague, but just streaming where you don't download parts at once. You view the video as it comes. He was mentioning different streaming protocols.